# Array value comparison with a multidimension array ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

If i have 2 arrays like let's say :

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
arr2 = [[2,4],12]
```

i would like to return variable  :

```
result=[1,3]
```

How can i create a variable that returns the indexes from arr1 that corresponds to the values from the arr2 nested array.

Comment: Why would you expect the result to be `[1,3]` and not `[[1,3], nil]`?

Comment: Few nitpicks as well - you never return a variable. You return values.  Variable is a placeholder, a reference to some value. Variables do not return anything.

Comment: basically what i want to do is
take arr1 values and check wich ones match arr2[0] values (in my case it is 2 and 4)
then i would like to print out the index of arr1 that contains the matching value ( in my case index is 1 and 3)

Comment: That would mean you just want to ignore all the other elements of that array except for the first? Your requirements are pretty ill-defined and for now can be satisfied by simple `return [1,3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you would need to flatten your second multidimensional array, and afterwards just find that item index in the first one.

```rb
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
arr2 = [[2,4],12]

def find_indexes(arr1, arr2)
  arr2.flatten.each_with_object([]) do |item, acc|
    index = arr1.index(item).to_i
    acc << index if index >= 0
  end
end

find_indexes(arr1, arr2)
#=> [1,3]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the second array was: `arr2 = [[1,4],12]`

Comment: yeah, `acc << index if index > 0` is wrong, it should be `acc << index if index`. Also, you may have duplicates in the result: `find_indexes([1,2,3,4,5,6], [[2,4],2])
=> [1, 3, 1]`